# SQL Server 2008 joining

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax

I have some tables in my database & I want to combine them by using join but I have got a problem. Let me make it clear. I have assigned `Id_num` (column name) as primary key in the `Stu_info` table & the other tables have an `Id_num` column to store ID number.

All tables have same name (`Id_num`) of that column which will store ID number. I have tried to make a view to connect tables to get specific data from specific tables. If I use `INNER JOIN` then it doesn't show any rows because of some null vales. However I have used `LEFT OUTER JOIN` it is working. But it makes a problem which is not acceptable.

Code :

```
SELECT     
    dbo.Stu_info.Id_num, dbo.Development_fee.Dvf, dbo.Stu_info.Stu_name, 
    dbo.Stu_info.Dep_name, dbo.Tuition_fee.Acy, dbo.Tuition_fee.Tui_fee, 
    dbo.Registration_fee.Reg_fee, dbo.Form_fill_up_fee.Acy AS Expr1, 
    dbo.Form_fill_up_fee.FFF, dbo.Examination_fee.E_typ, dbo.Examination_fee.Exm_fee, 
    dbo.monthly_instal.Instm, dbo.monthly_instal.Paid
FROM
    dbo.Stu_info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Tuition_fee ON dbo.Stu_info.Id_num = dbo.Tuition_fee.Id_num 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Registration_fee ON dbo.Stu_info.Id_num = dbo.Registration_fee.Id_num 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Examination_fee ON dbo.Stu_info.Id_num = dbo.Examination_fee.Id_num 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.monthly_instal ON dbo.Stu_info.Id_num = dbo.monthly_instal.Id_num 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Development_fee ON dbo.Stu_info.Id_num = dbo.Development_fee.Id_num 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Form_fill_up_fee ON dbo.Stu_info.Id_num = dbo.Form_fill_up_fee.Id_num
```

For example `Dvf` column of `Development_fee` table has one data & `Tui_fee` column of `Tuition_fee` table has six data for a student who has following ID `LAB10161117`.

Now if you try to use following code

```
Select * from View_1
Where Id_num = 'LAB10161117'
```

to get data for following ID LAB10161117 then you suppose to get following information. Like

```
ID number : LAB10161117
-----------------------------------------
Development Fee  ---- Tuition Fee ---- Other columns
10000            ----  1000
Null             ----  1000
Null             ----  1000
Null             ----  1000
Null             ----  1000
Null             ----  1000
```

Because `Dvf` column of `Development_fee` table has one entry for `LAB10161117` which is `10000` & `Tui_fee` column of `Tuition_fee` table has six entries for `LAB10161117` which are `1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000`. But it doesn't show like above information. When I execute following code to show data for that ID

```
Select * from View_1
Where Id_num = 'LAB10161117'
```

then it shows wrong information like

```
ID number : LAB10161117
-----------------------------------------
Development Fee  ---- Tuition Fee ---- Other columns

10000            ----  1000
10000        ----  1000
10000       ----  1000
10000        ----  1000
10000       ----  1000
10000       ----  1000
```

which is not right! It means to match with `Tuition_fee` table which has six rows it has been generated same value of `Development_fee` table again & again (six times) though `Development_fee` table has only one row for that person who has following ID `LAB10161117`.

All I want to show row exactly what is present there in table & I want to stop row duplication. Would you please help me to solve this problem? Please help me to get rid of this problem. Thank you.

Comment: it would be easier to help .. if you did a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/about.html) representing your problem.

Comment: Narrow your problem down and show examples of your data and what you want the results to be.  So, for example, you have 1 `development_fee` record and 6 `tuition_fee` records.  When you join these together you don't want the `development_fee` record duplicated.  *But what **do** you want to happen?*  By showing us the input data you have and the output data you desire, we can help you get what you want.

Comment: First of all sorry maybe I couldnt explain it properly. However all I want to show record exectly what is present there in table thats it & I want to stop record duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to work with UNION rather then a JOIN.

Simplifying your query the union might look like this

```
SELECT           dbo.Stu_info.Id_num, dbo.Development_fee.Dvf
FROM             dbo.Stu_info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.Tuition_fee ON dbo.Stu_info.Id_num = dbo.Tuition_fee.Id_num 
UNION
SELECT           dbo.Stu_info.Id_num, dbo.Registration_fee.Reg_fee
FROM             dbo.Stu_info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.Registration_fee ON dbo.Stu_info.Id_num = dbo.Registration_fee.Id_num
```

Comment: Would you please tell me how should I use UNION there in my code? I dont have enough idea about Oracle as a result it will be hard enough for me to adjust this code with my code.

Comment: See the newest edit. Hope this works for you. Just repeat in each select what you need to have from stu_info table and do a join on the next table. Actually you might want to do a INNER JOIN again as some fees are not there for a student at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have to study it. But how should I use it there in my code(full code)?

Comment: Please figure it out for yourself. It is no more difficult. How did you write the SELECT statement? Was that generated or did you code it yourself? If it was generated I suggest you to sit down and do some reading about SQL SELECT statements. It actually is quite easy.

Comment: SELECT     dbo.Stu_info.Id_num, dbo.Tuition_fee.Acy, dbo.Tuition_fee.Tui_fee 
FROM         dbo.Stu_info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tuition_fee ON dbo.Stu_info.Id_num = dbo.Tuition_fee.Id_num
UNION
SELECT     dbo.Stu_info.Id_num, dbo.Development_fee.Dvf 
FROM         dbo.Stu_info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Development_fee ON dbo.Stu_info.Id_num = dbo.Development_fee.Id_num 
UNION
SELECT     dbo.Stu_info.Id_num, dbo.Registration_fee.Reg_fee
FROM         dbo.Stu_info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Registration_fee ON dbo.Stu_info.Id_num = dbo.Registration_fee.Id_num

Comment: UNION
SELECT     dbo.Stu_info.Id_num, dbo.Form_fill_up_fee.Acy, dbo.Form_fill_up_fee.FFF
FROM         dbo.Stu_info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Form_fill_up_fee ON dbo.Stu_info.Id_num = dbo.Form_fill_up_fee.Id_num
UNION
SELECT     dbo.Stu_info.Id_num, dbo.Examination_fee.E_typ, dbo.Examination_fee.Exm_fee 
FROM         dbo.Stu_info

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.Examination_fee ON dbo.Stu_info.Id_num = dbo.Examination_fee.Id_num       
UNION           
SELECT     dbo.Stu_info.Id_num, dbo.monthly_instal.Instm, dbo.monthly_instal.Paid
FROM         dbo.Stu_info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.monthly_instal ON dbo.Stu_info.Id_num = dbo.monthly_instal.Id_num

Comment: As you told me to use UNION. I have done it but it shows error! SQL Execution Error.
Executed SQL statement: SELECT dbo.Stu_info.Id_num,
dbo.Tuition_fee.Acy, dbo.Tuition_fee.Tui_fee FROM dbo.Stu_info LEFT
OUTER JOIN dbo.Tuition_fee ON dbo.Stu_info.Id_num = dbo.Tuition_fee.Id_num UNION SELECT dbo.Stu_info.Id_num,
dbo.Development_fee.Dvf FROM dbo.Stu_info LEF...
Error Source : .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Error Message : All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: "must have an equal number of expressions". Make sure every single select is having the same number of columns of the same type.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reminding me. I have used same number of columns of same type & its working but problem is that it shows ID number & Tuition Fee only! What about another fields?

Comment: Be honest, did you understand the UNION select at all? Maybe you read some SQL tutorial.

Comment: I have understood it but it doesnt fulfil my demand. Didnt you get what exectly I am looking for?

Comment: It sounds to me like you would like the full code written for you. But this is not the purpose of this site.

Comment: I have already written it & tried to show it. Even followed your instruction. But it didnt provide me that result what I am looking for.

Comment: Well it won't do it exactly as you have said in the question. That is impossible to be done with a query. The only way is to use a Join after the UNION. What you could do but then it gets a bit complicated, is to make the union a VIEW and then Join itself on the view for its fee type.